# Trying to display 2 tables

Tags: vbscript

I tried to display 2 tables using this code but it only display the table two, I am really not sure why does it not display table two here is my piece of code.

```
sub ExecQry
        parent.frames(1).DataForm.Query.value = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Something = " &some.value
        parent.frames(1).DataForm.Query.value = "SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE something = " &some.value
        parent.frames(1).DataForm.submit
    end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

becouse you override the table one try useing this

```
sub ExecQry
    parent.frames(1).DataForm.Query.value = "SELECT * FROM Table1,Table2 WHERE 
    Something = " &some.value
    parent.frames(1).DataForm.submit
    end sub
```

I used Joins to work arround on it

Comment: new line? Where?